# Informatica character sequence

Tags: informatica, sequence-generators

I am trying to create character sequence like AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD,....,BAA, BAB, BAC,.... and So on in a flat file using Informatica. I have the formula to create the charater sequence.

Here I need to have sequence numbers generated in informatica. But I dont have any source file or database to have this source.

Is there any method in Informatica to create sequence using Sequence Generater when there is no source records to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to generate rows without a source in a mapping.

When I need to do that I use one of these methods :

- Generating a file with as many lines as I need, with the `seq` command under Unix. It could also be used as a direct pipeline source without creating the file.
- Getting lines from a database

For example Oracle can generate as many lines as you want with a hierarchical query :

```
SELECT LEVEL just_a_column
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 26*26*26
```

DB2 can do that with a recursive query :

```
WITH DUMMY(ID) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 1 FROM DUMMY WHERE ID < 26*26*26
)
SELECT ID FROM DUMMY
```

Comment: Your reply is too informative.. But level in oracle is not working for 15000000.. This is the sequence i was trying to create... Anyhow good piece of information... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

This is bit tricky as Informatica will do row by row processing and your mapping won't initialize until you give source rows through input(File or DB). So for generating sequence of n length by Informatica trnasformations you need n rows in input.
Another soltion to this is to use Dummy Source(i.e. Source with one row) and you can pass the loop parameters from this source and then use Java transfornmation and Java code to generate this sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your input... I will use Java Transformation

Answer (score 1):

You can generate rows using Java transformation. But even to use that , you need a source. I suggest you to use the formula in the Java transform and a dummy source to a database with a select getdate() statement so that a record is returned to call the Java transform. You can then generate the sequence as well in Java transform or connect sequence generator to output of Java transform to number them.

Answer (score 0):

We have an option to create a sequence number even it is not available in the source.

1. Create a Sequence generator transformation. You will be getting NEXTVAL and CURRVAL.
2. In a property tab you will be having an option the create a sequence numbers.

   - Start values - the value from which it should start
   - Increment by - increment value
   - End value - the value in which it should end
   - Current value - your current value
   - Cycle - In case you require in cyclic
   - No.of cached values
   - Reset
   - Tracing level
3. Connect the NEXTVAL to your target column.